# What genre are groups like Chevelle, Helmet, Tool

Tags: genre, metal

Do all these groups fall in the same genre?  If so, what genre is it?

A Perfect Circle
Breaking Benjamin
Bullet for my Valentine
Chevelle
Deftones
Helmet
Linkin Park (early work)
Nine Inch Nails
Red
Rise Against
Seether
Slipknot
Soundgarden
Staind
Sum 41
System of a Down
Thirty Seconds to Mars (early work)
Three Days Grace
Tool

Comment: @BCdotWEB This isn't soliciting recommendations, it's asking to identify a genre, which is on topic.

Answer (score 6):

These are different genres of music. Tool and A Perfect Circle are progressive metal/rock, sum 41 are punk etc. If I had to chose one common root/genre for all of them I would say rock/metal.

Comment: I have to agree with this.  NIN is often lumped into Industrial Metal. Tool is it's own genre, practically.  Linkin Park was Nu Metal.  The rest are a combo of Rock/Punk/Metal.  But if I had to look at them all from 30,000 feet, I'd say Metal

Comment: I would not put most of these in metal -- they're a bit light in certain areas of their sound to be metal. Of the ones I have listened to, Tool is perhaps the closest and does incorporate many elements from metal.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I agree. They are different genres with rock being their common root.

Answer (score 1):

As papakias and Johnny Bones correctly point out these bands cover many genres eg Soundgarden - Grunge/Heavy Rock/Metal. Slipknot - Metal. Rise Against - Punk.  System of a Down - Metal. Seether - Grunge. Three Days Grace - Rock. Nine Inch Nails - Industrial/Techno. Tool - Prog.

I do disagree however on these bands being under the Rock/Metal or Metal genres though. Some of these bands contain no elements that could be considered Metal (specifically the modern day interpretation of Metal in which Led Zeppelin and Deep Purple, originally known as Metal bands are now labeled Classic Rock or Heavy Rock).

So I would have to say Heavy Rock as a blanket genre that would cover these diverse bands.